# ServletActionContext.getServletContext returns null

Tags: struts2

one of the action class  has following **fromDate** field. whose value coming from jsp file which is proper. And using ServletContextAware interface setting the fromDate value using
contex.setAttribute as follows.
1)Scenario-1

```
public class Search extends ActionSupport implements ServletContextAware {
    private String fromDate;
    public String getFromDate() {
        return fromDate;
    }
    public void setFromDate(String fromDate) {
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
    }
}

@Override
public void setServletContext(ServletContext ctx) {
    ctx.setAttribute("startDate", getFromDate());   
}
```

Now in the some other action class inside the execute method i am fetching its value as follows.

```
public String execute() {
    ServletContext context = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();
    String obj = (String)context.getAttribute("startDate");
```

obj value is showing null.

while setting the context variable in first action class as follows

```
2)Scenario-2
    public class Search extends ActionSupport implements ServletContextAware {
        private String fromDate;
        public String getFromDate() {
            return fromDate;
        }
        public void setFromDate(String fromDate) {
            this.fromDate = fromDate;
        }

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext ctx) {
        ctx.setAttribute("startDate", "Test message");  
    }
}
```

Now in the some other action class inside the execute method i am fetching its value as follows.

```
public String execute() {
    ServletContext context = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();
    String obj = (String)context.getAttribute("startDate");
```

obj value is showing "Test message" which is proper

**I need to pass the dynamic "private String fromDate"** inside ctx.setAttribute which is coming from jsp as mentioned in first scenario.

My requirement is I can set the variable(fromDate) in first action class. And in any other action class i need to use that variable.
Please help me. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: You're doing things in the wrong order, but ultimately it depends on the order of your interceptors which will be called first, the param set, or the context set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dave already mentioned, you are doing it in WRONG order. The time when you set the attribute in context, fromDate is null since it's set after that.

Instead of setting the attribute in setServletContext(...), why not set it in the actions' execute method!

```
public String execute(){
    ServletActionContext.getServletContext().setAttribute("startDate", getFromDate());
}
```

And then you can use it in the second action.